# In LWC, how can I make a lightning-button use the full width available to it?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have built a form using **lightning-record-edit-form** & have added a button to it using **lightning-button**.  I want the button to have 100% width, so I added a class to **lightning-button** that sets **display:block** and **width:100%** but I'm not getting the results I was hoping for.

Here is the relevant markup:

```
<lightning-button 
   type="submit" 
   variant="brand" 
   label="Create Case" 
   class="stretchButton slds-p-top_x-small"></lightning-button>
```

And here is the CSS definition:

```
.stretchButton {display:block; width: 100%;}
```

And here's a screenshot of the result in the console.
[image]

As you can see, **lightning-button** element has been set to 100% width, but the underlying **button** element has not.

Does anyone have any advice on how to set the underlying button's width to 100%?

Comment: did you try min-width ?

Comment: `class` doesn't seem to be an attribute for [`lightning-button`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/specification), so I doubt if having anything there will have any effect.

Comment: the screenshot seems to  imply that the class name is being properly handled by the component

Comment: @glls: Yes, **lightning-button** is at a 100%.  But the underlying **button** is not.  In the template markup there is only one element called **lightning-button**, but in the HTML output, a child element called **button** is added.  It is this child I am trying to affect.  But sadly since it's not in my template, I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Actually - you wont be able to =(

Comment: Per @mike537, use the stretch attribute.  (I can't submit this as an answer because this question was, incorrectly, closed as a duplicate).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't style the underlying `button` of a `<lightning-button>`.

There is an SLDS class for this though:

`<button type="submit" class="slds-button slds-button_brand slds-button_stretch">Create Case</button>`

*Edit clarification:*

As [glls](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/31663/glls) pointed out below and [elsewhere](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/253163/25289), you can't style child components from parents (or siblings for that matter) due to LWC's use of Shadow DOM.

When you apply the classes below to the `lightning-button`, you actually get a "button" within a button, as you can kind of see in the screenshot of the LWC Button and can see more clearly when using developer tools to inspect the elements.

```
    <div class="slds-p-around_small">
        <button type="submit" class="slds-button slds-button_brand slds-button_stretch">HTML Button</button>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="LWC Button" title="LWC Button" class="slds-button slds-button_brand slds-button_stretch"></lightning-button>
    </div>
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks!  That did it!  I had tried **slds-button_stretch** on its own, but I had not tried to use it in conjunction with **slds-button** and **slds-button_brand**.  When all three are used, the underlying button will stretch to the available width.

Comment: One minor edit on your answer to help others in the future: could you change the element to **lightning-button** instead of **button**.

Comment: this doesn't aesthetically works with neutral buttons since both the buttons have border and both borders are visible

Comment: I would recommend NOT using this method. First, this poses some accessibility issues due to the focus being buried on the "inner" button. Second the hover states get too confusing.

Comment: I don't remember which release this was a part of, but now there is an attribute called 'stretch' in lightning-button that will fully expand the width. See [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-button/documentation)

Answer (score 8):

Basically, you wont be able to change it because styles defined in a component’s style sheet are scoped to the component and your CSS cannot reach into the child component of the lightning-button component.
You will have to add your own custom button:

button-lwc

```
<button type="button" name="Submit Case" value="Submit Case" class="stretchButton slds-button slds-button_brand" onclick={handleClick} >Submit Case</button>
```

button.css

```
.stretchButton{
    display:block;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

the first button is the namespaced lighnting-button component,
the second one is the [slds blueprint](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/buttons/).

Comment: +1 beauty of shadow dom.

Comment: Sorry. but Jake's answer is better.

Comment: its fine =), as long as you have been served