# Variant label-hidden with Lightning Input Field and LWC not hiding HelpText Icon?

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, lightning-base-component, lwc-dom

I've seen various [posts](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005mfcQAA) about how you cab hide stray elements like this with aura components, and I think the answer with LWC is always 'shadow-dom' as described [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253161/changing-colors-of-lightning-button)  but is there really no way to hide the help icon on a Lightning Input Field when you set the label to be hidden?

```
<lightning-input-field 
key={item.submittedDataField} 
field-name={item.submittedDataField} 
onchange={onInputChange}
title={item.submittedDataField} 
variant="label-hidden" >
</lightning-input-field>
```

The label is hidden but it still shows the help icon:

[image: But it still shows the help icon]

I can see the element I think I want to hide in the Chrome Dev Console:

[image]

But no combination of css seems to be able to hide it e.g.

```
.slds-form-element__icon {
    display: none !important;
}

:host (.slds-form-element__icon) {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You always read shadow dom because that is the reason - by definition you can`t style web components from outside (and lightning-input field is a new component context). Thats how the shadow boundaries are defined in the spec.

Right now it is possible to workaround it by loading a global style via [loadStyle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/create_third_party_library)
because salesforce is not using the real / native shadow dom. But this approach is disencouraged by salesforce and is not guaranteed to work for ever (especially if we will ever see the native shadow dom on platform - you will notice that it is already not possible in the default settings of OSS Lwcs). Up to you to decide - besides that option you can`t change it as long the component does not give you the ability to