# Change the color of Lightning-Output-Field

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
 <lightning-output-field variant="label-hidden" field-name="Company__c">
                            </lightning-output-field>
```

it showing black i want to change the color of my output how i can achieve this

Comment: you can't - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/253161/changing-colors-of-lightning-button

Comment: You can. Check this blog post:
https://hellosnl.blogspot.com/2019/07/lwc-override-css-of-standard-lightning-components.html